# Scrollbar with grid inside grid using css grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a html page that I don't want to scroll at the body scope, however, when using css grids that are nested, I can't control the body's scrollbar when content inside a nested grid overflows even when it has the property to scroll on overflow. The snippet I provide below I have a container which has grid and it contains a grid-area called workspace which has a component that is also a css grid. The component has content that forces the whole body to scroll, where I only want the content to scroll. I try messing with heights to 100% and 100vh, but no such luck.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
}


.container {
  background-color: #282828;
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-rows: 42px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'tabs sidebar'
        'workspace sidebar';
    height: 100vh;
}

.tabs {
    grid-area: tabs;
    background-color: violet; 
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: tomato;
    min-width: 50px;
}

.workspace {
    grid-area: workspace;
    background-color: blue;
}

.component {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'header'
      'content';
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     <div class="component">
       <div class="header">
         <h1>My header</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
          <h1>Temp</h1>
        <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>

       </div>
       
       
    </div>
    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you are looking for? do you want to get ride of the scrollbar?

Comment: No, I only want the scrollbar inside the content, however, when you run the scrip there two, but only the body scrolls.

Comment: check my answer did i get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a scrollbar the container should have a height that if the content exceed then the scrollbar will be activated so whenever you want to have a scrollbar you have to keep in your mind that the border of your container should be defined some how.

Now with that being said, if you don't want to have a fixed height then the main div should be a full screen then the nested container can have a scroll otherwise it will keep growing.

> the `full screen` because you don't want to provide any fixed height otherwise , if you have a fixed height then it will be more simple

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
}


.container {
  background-color: #282828;
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-rows: 42px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'tabs sidebar'
        'workspace sidebar';
    height: 100vh;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

.tabs {
    grid-area: tabs;
    background-color: violet; 
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: tomato;
    min-width: 50px;
}

.workspace {
    grid-area: workspace;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}

.component {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'header'
      'content';
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="workspace">
     <div class="component">
       <div class="header">
         <h1>My header</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
          <h1>Temp</h1>
        <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>
    <h1>Temp</h1>

       </div>
       
       
    </div>
    
  </div>  
</div>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but do you know how to achieve this without setting top of the content to a fixed value? I'm using Angular, so a lot of the content is dynamic.

Comment: There are multiple solutions but it depends on the layout you want to achieve, the only thing you need to focus on, is that your main div shouldn’t be able to grow.

Comment: You're right that I don't want my main div to grow, however, if the header grows then it's overlapping the content.

Comment: You get the help of jquery to calculate the top position but as i told you the code I provided is only to give you an idea